# Sklearn RFE with pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to use RFECV of Sklearn with a pipeline but I get the "could not covert string to float" for one of the values that is not in the columns in the categorical pipeline and numerical pipeline in the columntransformer. Does anyone know a solution? Here is my code for the pipeline and RFE:

```
data = {"num1": [1,2,3],"num2":[2,np.nan,2],"cat1":["high","low","high"],"cat2":["left","right","right"],
        "target":[4,5,5]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

cat_feat = ["cat2"]
num_feat = ["num1"]

X = data[["num1","num2","cat1","cat2"]]
y = data[["target"]]

cat_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))])

num_pipe = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median'),
    )

columntrans = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat", cat_pipe, cat_feat),
    ("num", num_pipe, num_feat)
    ],
    remainder="drop",
    n_jobs=-1
)

from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV, RFE
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor

et_pipeline = make_pipeline(columntrans, ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=200, 
                                                              random_state=42, n_jobs=-1))

RFE_model = RFECV(et_pipeline,scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=2, n_jobs=-1)
RFE_model = RFE_model.fit(X, y)
print(RFE_model.n_features_)
```

So the value error is for a value in a column that is not in cat_feat or num_feat.

EDIT: added error information and reproducible example.

```
RFE_model = RFE_model.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 693, in fit_transform
        return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\_rfe.py", line 508, in fit
        X, y = self._validate_data(
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 432, in _validate_data
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
        return f(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 796, in check_X_y
        X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
        return f(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 599, in check_array
        array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
      File "C:\Users\Timkr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'BHV'
```

Comment: Maybe X_train has a categorical column, which was not encoded (values are strings)

Comment: Yes there are some categorical columns that are not encoded in X_train but because of the remainder=drop, I expected those to not be used for the estimator. Should X_train only contain the categorical and numerical features even when remainder=drop?

Comment: What is the source of the error? SimpleImputer? or ExtraTreesRegressor?

Comment: You should just post a [example]. Does the error happen if there's only one sample? Can you inline the sample into the code? Can you reduce some unnecessary code?

Comment: I have included an example, the Value error is: could not convert string to float: 'high'. But high is not in the columns of the columntransformer